# Low-Budget Pre-Amp for Senn 416

Tags: pre-amp, sennheiser, 416, quality

Hello everyone.

My friend asked me to do some research for him on a preamp for a Sennheiser 416. I'm stumped as I have been working in a professional studio my whole career and don't know where to start looking.

The lower the cost the better. He didn't exactly give a price-range but I'm guessing around 300-500$. He doesn't want to break his bank but he doesn't want bad quality either. Does anyone have any recommendations they have used and were happy with that are consumer-pro quality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're only interested in mono, perhaps a Sound Devices MP-1 or MM-1?  I've not used them myself but you can't really go wrong with Sound Devices.

http://www.sounddevices.com/products/mm1master.htm
http://www.sounddevices.com/products/mp1master.htm

Answer (score 4):

Well it depends what you mean by "Low Budget". Matthew is right about the sound devices pre, and it would compliment your Senn pretty well.

It should be about $350, if you go with the MM-1.
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/292989-REG/Sound_Devices_MM_1_MM_1_Single_Channel_Portable.html#reviews

Comment: Thanks Tom! I'll send him this and tell you what he buys.

Answer (score 2):

If he needs it in the field I would highly recommend a Sound Devices MP-1. If he only needs one channel this will give him excellent quality, portability, and it's battery powered.

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch Matthew. I'll send him this info and let you know what he chooses.

Comment: True about the MP-1. However, if you have the extra 50 bucks the Headphone out on the MM-1 will come in very handy. Both models single channel and are battery powered. Depending on the type recorder its hooked up to, it might be a necessity. 

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I just quickly glanced at the MP-1 and didn't realize it had no headphone output.  The MM-1 would be a better option and well worth the extra $50.